# How to rotate(360°) a button if clicked on in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, kotlin

I want to rotate the settings button of my MainActivity if clicked on.

This is the code I wrote so far in the `MainActivity.kt` file:

```java
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

  //Spin Settings Button

  settings.setOnContextClickListener {  //First error
  settings.animate().setDuration(2).rotationBy(180f).start() //second error
      }
   }
}
```

Following this code I receive two errors:

First error:

> Call requires API level 23 (current min is 21): android.view.View#setOnContextClickListene....

Second Error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Boolean was expected

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Change contextClickListener to clickListener, all errors should gone

Comment: Thanks @Arthur all errors are gone. But I still need help with the rotation. It still doesn´t work and I can´t figure out why.

Comment: Not sure how it's in kotlin, but you need some how to call .animate() on clicked object, try to use "this" instead of settings in onClickListener

Comment: Set duration to 2000, in animations duration is in milliseconds.

Comment: @Arthur thanks man, this was the selution

Comment: Appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

try it :
its some code i use in my project

```
  RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 180, A 
  nimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
  rotate.setDuration(5000);
  rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

  ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

  image.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Comment: should I just put this in the onCreate function?

Comment: can you show me how to implement the code properly?

Comment: @JoyLucas 
if user clicked and you want to show rotation :
use inside onClickListener Object (Button)

Comment: what do I need to import in order to use RotateAnimation?